# How to find parent implicit parameter with scala-reflect?

Tags: scala, scala-reflect

I have two classes:

```
class X[A](implicit ord: Ordering[A]) // + other irrelevant parameters
class Y[A: Ordering] extends X[A]
```

Given a `Symbol` corresponding to `Y`'s implicit constructor parameter, I want to find the symbol for the parent class implicit parameter it corresponds to (if one exists).

```
val yOrdSym = ...
val yOrdType = yOrdSym.typeSignature
val xImplicitParams = 
  xSym.primaryConstructor.paramLists.flatten.
  filter(xParam => xParam.isImplicit && ???)
```

Now I need to filter it for having the same type as well (or a supertype, but this doesn't matter for my usecase). I've tried `xParam.typeSignature =:= yOrdSym.typeSignature`, which didn't work. This makes sense, because the type parameters have different owners. However, `xParam.typeSignature =:= yOrdSym.typeSignatureIn(xSym.toType)` and `xParam.typeSignatureIn(ySym.toType) =:= yOrdSym.typeSignature` don't work either. How to do it correctly?

Comment: If I were you, I'd try one of the two approaches: 1) https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/1fbce4612c21a4d0c553ea489b4765494828c09f/src/reflect/scala/reflect/api/Types.scala#L366 passing type parameters from X and Y, 2) stripping off type arguments from typeSignatures and comparing the rest.

Comment: Stripping type arguments doesn't work (e.g. I could have two type parameters with the same context bound in both classes). The first should work, though.